# MIgración SQL Server - MySQL - Clave Primaria UUID

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

Estoy realizando una migración de una base de datos SQL Server a MySQL. En la base de datos de origen las claves primarias (y por lo tanto las foráneas) son de tipo uniqueidentifier.
En MYSQL no existe este tipo de forma nativa y la "solución" propuesta en convertir este tipo a VARCHAR(36). Me preocupa el rendimiento de la base de datos teniendo como clave primaria una cadena de texto.
¿Cual podría ser la mejor solución para esta migración?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: [Según el MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mssql-typemapping.html), el equivalente a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` en MySQL sería un `VARCHAR(64)`. En cuanto a tu duda sobre el rendimiento, hay ventajas y desventajas en el uso de `UUID` como PK, [como se explica aquí](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-uuid/). ¿Qué es lo mejor? Eso no te lo podrá decir nadie con certeza, porque depende de muchas cosas. Haz pruebas y decide por ti mismo, según la realidad de tus datos (miles de millones de registros o miles de registros) y el contexto (el servidor de la NASA o un NAS).